# Internal Server Error showing after uploading my war file on server

Tags: jsp, javabeans

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

But its work fine on localhost, Please tell me where I am wrong.

My JSP

```
<jsp:useBean id="db" scope="request" class="logbean.LoginBean"> 
  <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value='<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>' /> 
  <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value='<%=request.getParameter("password")%>' />  
</jsp:useBean> 

<jsp:forward page="login/login"> 
  <jsp:param name="username" value="<%=db.getUserName()%>" /> 
  <jsp:param name="password" value="<%=db.getPassword()%>" /> 
</jsp:forward>
```

URL : [www.btlcargo.com/login/](http://www.btlcargo.com/login/)

username and password is admin,admin respectively

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the code for http://www.btlcargo.com/login/loginbean.jsp

Comment: <jsp:useBean id="db" scope="request" class="logbean.LoginBean">            
 <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value='<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>' />
 <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value='<%=request.getParameter("password")%>' />
</jsp:useBean>

<jsp:forward page="login/login">
 <jsp:param name="username" value="<%=db.getUserName()%>" />
 <jsp:param name="password" value="<%=db.getPassword()%>" />
</jsp:forward>

Comment: can you please format the code

Comment: sorry satya actually it is in formaterd but i dnt know why it is shlowing like this

Comment: what is login here : <jsp:forward page="login/login"> is it a servlet or a jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server logs. If you have deployed web application on Tomcat then check `tomcat/logs/localhost.2012-07-17.log`.

There  should be logs file for each day like `localhost.2012-07-17.log`